# Php Url Parameters and BlueHost

Tags: php, mysql, get

I am having troubles using my `url` parameters to write to a blue host DB.

As soon as I pass parameters into the `url` I get a `server error(500)`.

I am also not receiving any error reports on the `PHP` side.

what am I doing wrong?

I have reloaded the page, cleared all cookies, and I am fairly sure it is not a `gateway Timeout`.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

There are a couple more .htacces rules but those contain this:

```
 # Use PHP54CGI as default
 AddHandler fcgid54-script .php

# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

---

What i suggest is using a different hosting provider as this problem is not easy to be solved.
I moved my database to a different provider and it works now.

However this does not solve the problem for people who encounter the same

---

Comment: multiple.. i installed wordpress aswell.
theres not much in it..

updated in quest.

Comment: Try replacing the cgi handler with standard php handler `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php` and see if that works.

Comment: @RahilWazir help me out. there should be only one .htaccess in one directory or?

Comment: @nbin that doesn't really matter. i deleted the .htacces apart from the one that has the '<ifModule>' and it stil doesn't work
 Bluehost created an '.htacces.bak.11398014320' and a '.htacces.old' file on the same root level '/www'.

Comment: put both contents in one .htaccess and try.

Comment: @nbin didn't work either, i've scorched through the php.ini file and put all error logs etc to ON but that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

By any chance are you using the shared secure URL like "https://secure.bluehost.com/~userid" ?

I discovered that the .htaccess code for php 5.4:

```
AddHandler fcgid54-script .php
```

causes a failure when using the shared SSL url. Of course when you take it out, you are back on php 5.2.